# Procedures always returns empty results

Tags: mysql

I cant get this code to return me anything, i used to have the code in 2 functions and it always returned a random first name and a random last name but ever since i tried putting the code into this procedure it doesnt return anything, either empty results or just nothing happens after submitting the CALL command

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS IdGenerator;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE IdGenerator(tempCntry varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE rndm1 INT;
    DECLARE rndm2 INT;
    DECLARE rndmPlier INT;
    DECLARE firstN varchar(255);
    DECLARE lastN varchar(255);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pplGrp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pplGrp(FirstName_tmp varchar(255), LastName_tmp varchar(255));
    SELECT MAX(ChancesEnd) INTO rndmPlier FROM personlist WHERE country = tempCntry;
    SET rndm1 = FLOOR((1+RAND() * (rndmPlier-1))); 
    SELECT p.name INTO firstN FROM personlist p WHERE country = tempCntry AND FirstName = 1 AND sex = 0 AND p.ChancesStart <= rndm1 AND p.ChancesEnd >= rndm1 LIMIT 1;
    SET rndm2 = FLOOR((1+RAND() * (rndmPlier-1))); 
    SELECT p.name INTO lastN FROM personlist p WHERE country = tempCntry AND LastName = 1 AND sex = 0 AND p.ChancesStart <= rndm2 AND p.ChancesEnd >= rndm2 LIMIT 1;
    INSERT INTO pplGrp (FirstName_tmp, LastName_tmp)values(firstN, lastN);
    SELECT * FROM pplGrp;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Just one thing to keep on mind `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS pplGrp;`

Comment: I seem to have found the problem, it looks as if i have the SELECT * FROM pplGrp inside the procedure it doesn't display the table and that i have to make it non temporary for it to be able to display, not the solution i wanted but its something

Comment: pplgrp seems unnecessary. You just use it to stick two values in and immediately select them. How about deleting all of pplGrp lines and ending with: SELECT firstN,lastN;

Comment: and, they may not display the results, but the results are there if you were using this from any kind of program. just running the client isn't typically useful. maybe you want to do a cREATE VIEW

Comment: Well i want to be able to generate multiple People so thats why i need to insert them into a table so i can retrieve them later.

Comment: If you want to store multiple people so stop dropping and creating the same table, **or** as @GarrGodfrey explained: pplgrp is not necessary.